# How to attach dijit/menu to a node without using id's?

Tags: javascript, dojo

According to the Dojo documentation for [dijit/menu](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Menu.html)
you can attach a menu to a node by specifying the id's of the node.  Like in their example

```
  require([
  "dijit/Menu",
  "dijit/MenuItem",
  "dijit/CheckedMenuItem",
  "dijit/MenuSeparator",
  "dijit/PopupMenuItem",
  "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(Menu, MenuItem, CheckedMenuItem, MenuSeparator, PopupMenuItem){

    var pMenu;
    pMenu = new Menu({
        targetNodeIds: ["progmenu"]
    });
    ...
    ...
    pMenu.startup();
  });
```

Node

```
<span id="progmenu">Right click me to get a menu</span>
```

However I cannot use Id's in my project.  I need to use attach points.  How can I attach a menu to a node by attach point instead?

Answer (score 4):

Most places in Dojo where you can specify the id of a DOM node, you can specify the node itself as an alternative, assuming you can get a reference to it (as is the case with the attach point).

If the progmenu attach point refers to a widget, point at the widget's domNode.

```
pMenu = new Menu({
    targetNodeIds: [this.progmenu.domNode]
});
```

If the attach point is a DOM node, use attach point directly, or whatever variable contains a reference to the node.

```
pMenu = new Menu({
    targetNodeIds: [this.progmenu]
});
```

Another option is to use [dijit/Menu](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.10/dijit/Menu.html).bindDomNode, using the same tricks to get to the node.